# File Excel Created From Apache POI Can't Open by Ms Excel (file corrupt)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I don't know why the file I write using POI cant be opened by Ms Excel , but the file is still readable by POI. (cell value can be changed)
I use Apache-Poi 3.10 Final and JDK 1.5

Link file: http://www.corteconti.it/export/sites/portalecdc/_documenti/controllo/sez_autonomie/2016/schemi_di_bilancio_armonizzato_2015_ens_art_1_delibera_12_2016_sezaut_inpr.xls

here is the code

```
    String nomeFileArt1 = "schemi_di_bilancio_armonizzato_2015_ens_art_1_delibera_12_2016_sezaut_inpr.xls";
        NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + nomeFileArt1));
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs.getRoot(), true);

        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "schemi_di_bilancio_armonizzato.xls");
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Dati_Anagrafici");
        HSSFRow sheetrow = sheet.getRow(10);
        if (sheetrow == null) {
            sheetrow = sheet.createRow(10);
        }
        HSSFCell cell = sheetrow.getCell(0);
        if (cell == null) {
            cell = sheetrow.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        }
        cell.setCellValue("test");
        wb.write(stream);
        stream.close();
```

Comment: Apache POI 3.10 is rather old, [and there have been a huge number of bug fixes since then](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.10-FINAL). What happens when you upgrade to the most recent version and try again?

Comment: I also tried it with version 3.14. same problem

Comment: looks like something in the original spreadsheet confuses POI, because even not changing anything in the spreadsheet before writing it out makes it unreadable in Excel. You might need to create a bug-report for Apache POI to let us take a closer look.